# cakephp: how to destroy cakephp cookies on page refresh and on closing browser window

Tags: cakephp, cookies, destroy

How to destroy cakephp cookies on page refresh or when I close the browser window?

my code:
merry_parents_controller.php

```
 $this->Cookie->write('MerryParent.id',$this->MerryParent->id,false,0);
                    echo 'cookie MerryParent.id: '.$this->Cookie->read('MerryParent.id');
                    $this->set('id',$this->Cookie->read('MerryParent.id'));
```

thanks.

Comment: Destroy on page refresh? Why do you set the cookie in the first place if it should be destroyed immediately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using 0 as the last parameter will mean the cookie will be deleted when the session finishes (browser is closed).

i.e, `$this->cookie->time = 0;`

If you want to destroy cookies all the time (no idea why), add functionality to do so in your AppController's `beforeFilter()`, i.e `$this->cookie->delete('MerryParent');` (will delete entire MerryParent key).

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for all your answers. Actually the problem was when I clicked on login link for the first time, login link displays fine. But, the next time i click on login link again, login page doesn't display, instead report_card page (ie. the login redirect page) displays. The reason is, i didn't have a logout button anywhere on my webpage, so the user was logged on all the time. Thanks.

Comment: hi Ivo, when u say, the cookie will be deleted when the session finishes does that mean the browser will not remember that particular user when the user returns to that website?

Comment: The browser should remember the user if he comes back without having closed the browser in the mean time. I would always recommend something like a 10 minute to 1 hour session cookie, with an option for a token cookie to have 'stay-logged-in' functionality.

Comment: From my reading, cookies are stored in the user's browser. So, if the expiry is set to 0, the MerryParent key is still there, so even if the user closes the browser and comes back to the site later, he will not need to relogin right?

Comment: No; using 0, the cookie will only last as long as the browser is open. Set the cookie to 1 year's worth of seconds to have it last that long (make it persistent).

Comment: Ok, i got it. Thanks a lot for ur prompt replies. :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you want to imitate the behavior of [flash messages](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1467/flash). If that's right, you may be interested in [this part](http://api13.cakephp.org/view_source/session-helper/#line-136) of SessionHelper source code.

If I should simplify it for you, it would look like this (in a controller):

```
$key = 'MerryParent.id';
$value = '';
if ($this->Session->check($key)) {
    $value = $this->Session->read($key);
    $this->Session->delete($key);
}
```

If this is not any helpful, please describe more of what you're trying to accomplish. Maybe there is a better way.

Comment: I know I should rather add a comment to the question instead of adding an answer as this is not an accurate answer. Unfortunately I don't have 50 points yet, so I can only add comments to my own posts. I won't be angry if you'll demote my answer :)